# configuring project settings file c#

Tags: c#, web-config, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to write the following in project settings:

```
Server.MapPath(@"~\Content\file.txt")
```

When I call that string in the project, It gives me error "illegal character". How can i call a file that is stored inside the project Content in project setting

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to `Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/file.txt")`, as a URI is expected, not a file path.